# node.js/express: use router.route() with middleware functions

Tags: node.js, express, router, middleware

I would like to use the method **route()** on an express router to service a specific route with different HTTP methods. The following code works fine:

```js
var express = require('express');
var router  = express.Router();

router.route('/register')
  .get(adm.signUpForm)
  .post(adm.signUp);
```

However, when trying to use a middleware on the post route, I'm getting stuck. The following code works:

```js
// LOGIN processing
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate("local", {
  successRedirect: '/',
  failureRedirect: '/login'
}), function(){
  //empty
});
```

Here, the middleware function passport.authenticate(...) is called to check if the user credentials are valid or not. Authenticated users get re-directed to the homepage at "/"; Unknown users (or with incorrect password) get re-directed back to the "/login" form.

Now, I would like to re-factor this code and use something similar to the code example shown above (sign-up route), i. e. I would like to use **router.route('/login).xxxx** to service HTTP request xxxx on route '/login'. How can I tell express to use my passport.authenticate middleware function on the POST request to '/login'?

```js
router.route('/login')
  .get(adm.loginForm)
  .post(<my-middleware-function ???>, adm.login);
```

... where **adm.loginForm** is the end-point function that issues the login form upon a **GET** request to /login and **adm.login** is the end-point function that should be called when the server receives a **POST** request on this route, i. e. once the login form is submitted.

To the best of my knowledge, the express (4.x) documentation doesn't mention anything about installing a middleware function for a specific route **and (at the same time)** a specific HTTP request. I know that *router.route('/login').use()* can be used to install a middleware function for *all* HTTP requests on this route, but I only want my middleware to be called upon POST requests.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add them where you mentioned:

```
router.route('/login').post(checkPassport, adm.login)
```

You can also chain them together:

```
router.route('/login').post(checkPassport).post(adm.login)
```

`checkPassport` is the middleware you'll need to write that handles the passport authentication logic

Comment: Hi Matt - thanks for the quick reply. You are right, it is possible to add a middleware function as indicated in your answer. I realize, that my problem is a different one: defining 'checkPassport' as separate function and using it as middleware function as shown in your example, the passport functionality doesn't seem to work - the browser never receives a reply to a POST request on route '/login' (= timing out). However, inlining the body of checkPassport as first parameter in method .post fixes the issue. Maybe a binding issue of sorts?

Comment: Solved it - it was, indeed, a problem with the way passport.authenticate needs to get used when it's not used as "inlined" middleware. Relates to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21631451/passport-middleware-for-node-js. The key sentence can be found in the docs of 'passport.js': "Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send a response."